# Button click event is not working - why so?

Tags: android

I am trying to click on dynamic generated button

```
  for (i = 0; i < Randombutton.size(); i++) {

        Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());

        //set button text
        btn.setText(String.valueOf(Randombutton.get(i)));

        //set button default color
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f2"));
        btn.setTextSize(36);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Button clickedBtn = (Button) v;
                //  Log.w("cliked",String.valueOf(clickedBtn.getText()));
                Log.w("cliked", "test");
            }
        });

        RandomButtonView.addView(btn);

    }
```

button is showing fine but click event is not working.

Comment: do you create one or more buttons ?

Comment: assign button id

Comment: @B.mansouri Yes I create more than one button.

Comment: @MiteshMachhoya But how can I . here I am generating button randomly

Comment: Try referring this link.  Hope that would help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823419/click-event-for-all-dynamic-generated-buttons-android

Comment: try setting onClickListener on post method of view. everything in code seem's fine

Comment: you must add an id to the button

Comment: @SureshSuthar  use btn.setId(i)

Comment: btw currently you are adding multiple button on top of each other!!
why will you do that?

Comment: @Anmol My requiment is like that, Here is i am generating 4 random button with 4 random number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722685/3395198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code and it's working fine. Please check at your end as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            // btn.setId(i);
            btn.setText(String.valueOf("Test : " + (i + 1)));
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f2"));
            btn.setTextSize(8);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button clickedBtn = (Button) v;
                    Toast.makeText(DynamicView.this, clickedBtn.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            layout_dynamic_content.addView(btn);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you I just change Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext()) to Button btn = new Button(this) now it working